# Appium Server: SyntaxError: Unexpected token | in JSON at position 87 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: appium, appium-ios

If i start the appium server (version 1.21.0) from terminal i get the following error message.
I tried to uninstall and reinstall, install old version, install beta, nothing changed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that there were requests running in the background.